# Why I can't extract this value from an CLOB XML using XMLType into a JDBC query?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc, clob

I am going crazy trying to use **xmltype** to extract XML field value from a **CLOB** field of an Oracle DB table.

So I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  'ENELSERV'    AS codcliente,
  'SL'          AS sottosistema,
  'DD01'        AS account,
  substr(xmltype(d.documento)
           .EXTRACT('//cbc:IssueDate/text()').getStringVal()
        , 1, 4) AS anno
 FROM coda_tx c,
      documenti_tx d
WHERE c.fk_tipo_doc = 99
  AND c.fk_stato = 1
  AND c.pk_coda = d.pfk_coda
  AND c.canale = 'STA'
  AND c.fk_piva_mittente = '05779711000'
```

If I perform this query into **Oracle SQL Developer** I obtain the espected result, this table with these 2 rows:

```
CODCLIENTE  SOTTOSISTEMA  ACCOUNT  ANNO
----------------------------------------
MYCLIENT    SL            DD01     2014
MYCLIENT    SL            DD01     2014
```

So the query works fine and I obtain the espected result.

Now I have to put the previous query into a JDBC DAO class and I done in this way:

```
public void getListaFatturePDF(String partitaIva) {
    System.out.println("INTO ottieniListaFatturePDF()");

    Blob blobFibalPdf;
    String sql;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("SELECT 'ENELSERV' as CODCLIENTE, 'SL' as SOTTOSISTEMA, 'DD01' as ACCOUNT, ");
    sb.append("substr(xmltype(d.documento).EXTRACT('//cbc:IssueDate/text()').getStringVal (),1,4) as ANNO ");
    sb.append("from coda_tx c, documenti_tx d ");
    sb.append("WHERE   C.FK_TIPO_DOC = 99 ");
    sb.append("AND C.FK_STATO = 1 ");
    sb.append("AND C.PK_CODA = D.PFK_CODA ");
    sb.append("AND C.CANALE='STA' ");
    sb.append("AND C.FK_PIVA_MITTENTE = '05779711000'");

    sql = sb.toString();

    try {
        statment = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("ResultSet obtained");

        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while(rs.next()){

            // Retrieve by column name:
            String codCliente = rs.getString("CODCLIENTE");
            String sottosistema = rs.getString("SOTTOSISTEMA");
            String account = rs.getString("ACCOUNT");
            String anno = rs.getString("ANNO");

            // Display values:
            System.out.println("codCliente: " + codCliente);
            System.out.println("sottosistema: " + sottosistema);
            System.out.println("account: " + account);
            System.out.println("anno: " + anno);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

The problem is that when the previous method is performed I obtain the correct valies of the **CODCLIENTE**, **SOTTOSISTEMA**, **ACCOUNT** fields but the **ANNO** field value is an empty String, infact this is what I obtain in the console (the println result):

```
INTO ottieniListaFatturePDF()
ResultSet obtained
codCliente: ENELSERV
sottosistema: SL
account: DD01
anno:
```

Why the previous query works fine if it is performed directly into **Oracle SQL Developer** but have this problem when I try to use it into my JDBC DAO method?

Could be maybe something related to character that have to be escaped into:

```
sb.append("substr(xmltype(d.documento).EXTRACT('//cbc:IssueDate/text()').getStringVal (),1,4) as ANNO ");
```

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Is `xmltype` necessary? If it is not, you could get the whole XML: `rs.getClob("documento").getAsciiStream();` Then you can use _xpath_ to get `IssueDate`. I know it's not what you want, but it could work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself. I change the JDBC driver into my project using the **ojdbc.jar** file that is into the **Oracle SQL Developer** installation directory (I think that is an older version but it wors).

This is the **MANIFEST.MF** of the don't working drive version:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.75-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 12.1.0.2.0
Repository-Id: JAVAVM_12.1.0.2.0_LINUX.X64_140630
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: JDBC
Specification-Version: 4.0
Main-Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
sealed: true

Name: oracle/sql/converter/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/converter_xcharset/
Sealed: false
```

And this is the **MANIFEST.MF** of the working one:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 1.5.0_24-rev-b08 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.2.0
Repository-Id: JAVAVM_11.2.0.2.0_LINUX_100812.1
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: JDBC
Specification-Version: 4.0
Main-Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
sealed: true

Name: oracle/sql/converter/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/converter_xcharset/
Sealed: false
```

Comment: Can you tell which version were you using (the one that fails) and which one are you using now (the one that works)? It could be useful.

Comment: @Albert both files are named ojdbc.jar (but have different weigth). How can I know the version?

Comment: Look in its `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Must be an entry named `Implementation-Version` or `Specification-Version` or, probably, both

Comment: @Albert edited my answer including the MANIFEST.MF of the 2 ojdbc.jar files. What can you say me about this? How can be possible that the oldest one works well and the newest one don't works?

Comment: Not a clue. I don't understand, either. Both version seem to be 4.0. As far as I know, version ojdbc4.jar were for DB Oracle 10.x.x.x, using Java 1.4 and 1.5.  At least, you get it work.